# Is there a guarantee of sizeof equality for a single-inheritance hierarchy of empty classes?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, sizeof

I have a hierarchy of state classes for a state machine:

```
class BaseState
{
public:
  virtual ~BaseState {}

  template<typename ToCompareWith>
  bool in() const
  {
    return (dynamic_cast<const ToCompareWith*>(this) != 0);
  }
};

class SubState : public BaseState {};
class SubSubState : public SubState {};
```

On my machine, sizeof returns 4 for all classes. I am wondering if this is consistent. I know that it is not for multiple inheritance as memory alignment is more complex. I want to know that, because I would like to use *placement new* (into the old state memory location) when transitioning into a new state (the current state instance is stored in a base class pointer). I know I could store statics of all my states somewhere, but that's not the point here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no guarantee about the size added by deriving an empty class from a base. The standard allows that no size is added.

Note, that replacing objects with a dtor/placement new only works when you are explicitly managing objects: for example, you can't change the type of a normal object on the stack. You can, however, use C++11 unrestricted unions. You'd just list all potential transistions and destroy/create the suitable member upon a state change. This way you are also not dependant on the object size.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Currently I am doing explicit delete and new but I was afraid of bad alloc exceptions in this low level part of the system. I will have a look into unrestricted unions. However, I need to make sure that MSVC 2010 already supports it.

Answer (score 0):

In theory I don't know if all instances of empty classes with virtual functions have the same size.

In practice, most C++ implementations are using an implicit [vtable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table) pointer inside such instances, and generally the size of that (implicit) `_vptr` member is the `sizeof(void*)`

To be standard conforming, you might make a `union` of all such classes (assuming C++11).

BTW, your usage of `dynamic_cast` might be inefficient.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know that dynamic_cast isn't very efficient, but those checks are not performed very often. There are some other functions I omitted here (i.e., exact state check where I use typeid - which is probably faster).